# Find average monthly per person cost from months with completed data only in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For each month I have actual data for non-employee costs which I receive from the accounts as and when they have the information. From this data I calculate an associated per person month cost as seen in the following image:

[image]

For the entries in column E that don't have any entry in column B I use the calculated Estimated per person cost per month in I2.

To calculate I2 I use G2/H2 where G2 is `=AVERAGE(B:B)` and H2 is `=AVERAGE(C5:C14)`. As there's no entries in some of the cells in B2 I average the whole column, however, for H2 I only wish to average the cells in column C that have an entry in column B.

Is there a formula I can place in cell  H2 that will average all enrtries in column C only if there's an entry in the same row in column B?

The data I have used for the dataset on  the left is:

| Month | Cost | Employees | Monthly Per Employee Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jun-21 |  | 45 | £554 |
| Jul-21 |  | 51 | £554 |
| Aug-21 |  | 56 | £554 |
| Sep-21 | £30,000 | 59 | £508.47 |
| Oct-21 | £32,000 | 61 | £524.59 |
| Nov-21 | £31,000 | 66 | £469.70 |
| Dec-21 | £45,000 | 66 | £681.82 |
| Jan-22 | £48,000 | 70 | £685.71 |
| Feb-22 | £35,000 | 71 | £492.96 |
| Mar-22 | £30,000 | 76 | £394.74 |
| Apr-22 | £44,000 | 80 | £550.00 |
| May-22 | £44,500 | 88 | £505.68 |
| Jun-22 | £62,000 | 88 | £704.55 |
| Jul-22 |  | 88 | £554 |
| Aug-22 |  | 88 | £554 |
| Sep-22 |  | 88 | £554 |
| Oct-22 |  | 88 | £554 |
| Nov-22 |  | 88 | £554 |
| Dec-22 |  | 88 | £554 |
| Jan-23 |  | 88 | £554 |
| Feb-23 |  | 88 | £554 |
| Mar-23 |  | 88 | £554 |

Comment: Try the averageif() function.

Comment: used the following but it seems to average the whole of column C: =AVERAGEIF(B:B,"<>0",C:C), any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Comment: fixed it: =AVERAGEIF(B:B,"<>",C:C)

Comment: `=AVERAGE(FILTER(C:C,ISNUMBER(B:B)))` will also work if you have a version of Excel which has dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Used the following as per the suggestion from Solar Mike:

=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"<>",C:C)

Comment: This is another bit of Excel's function behaviour that is not documented by Microsoft: the use of `"<>"` to mean non-empty cells for the **criteria** argument in functions such as `AVERAGEIF`, `SUMIF` and `COUNTIF`. Thanks for noting it.